# AWS CloudFormation Template error: ParameterReferenceToken is not present in the Mappings section

Tags: aws-cloudformation

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template error: Mapping named 'com.amazonaws.aws21.digester.tokens.ParameterReferenceToken@23807b15' is not present in the 'Mappings' section of template.

Does anyone know what the above error means?  My JSON template is in the following gist:   https://gist.github.com/mdolian/a80a8d7dd2dc6ee730fbb8c9244d9c3b

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

This was a silly but the error thrown wasn't very meaningful.  I was setting a parameter that I used for a mapping improperly so it was failing to find the value when I was doing a lookup.

Comment: Just had the same weird error... This led me straight to my answer.

Comment: How did you find which parameter it was?